# WPF binding to a UserControl property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a list of items, each of which contains a display property of a type inheriting from a user control.  The idea is each inheriting class can decide for itself what it wants to display for the user.   The items are themselves arranged in a DataTemplate for a tab control... something like...

```
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding FooList}">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TabItem Header="{Binding Name}">
                        ???
                    </TabItem>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        </TabControl>
```

And the classes in the foo observablecollection look like...

```
    public class IFoo
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public UserControl Display { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

What I can't figure out is how to add the display property where the ??? is in the XAML.  Is there a way to do this (trying to avoid doing it from the code behind)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is use the `ItemContainerStyle` property of `TabControl`:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding FooList}">
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}" />
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Display}" />
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```